# How to change value in a drop down list in Houdini with Python?

Tags: python, parameters, houdini

I have 2 problems:

1.

I don´t know hot to add 2 points in fuse node. 
I tried to write this:

```
union1.parm('querygroup').set (2)
union1.parm('querygroup').set (3)
union1.parm('tol3d').set(1.25)
```

and don't work
then I tried to write

```
grupo1=geo.createNode('group','G1')
#grupo1.parm(entity).set(2)
```

to select and group the points but I don't know how select and group the points in it

2.
I need to change the second value of the drop down list to the option B-A but i dont know hot to say to python that.

```
crear.parm('booleanop').set(3)
crear.parm('substractchoices')
```

I tried this.

I would appreciate it if you could help me fix it

IMAGES IN LINK=

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1C1v3DLgW4cz85PjCqK4hAFkk0wxrVWwp/view?usp=sharing
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1FbhEkyX29YHVExlaTlw8eg0oD98ajcV7/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 2):

In case you haven't already encountered a solution to your questions, see if the following helps to resolve:

1. `'querygroup'` looks for a string value to populate the Group field, so your attempt is almost there, but the following should work to set the Fuse Group field to be points 2 and 3:

   `union1.parm('querygroup').set ('2-3')`
2. To select the 2nd value of the Boolean subtract drop down list, use the menu tokens for that parameter.  In this case, the subtract choices are `'aminusb'`, `'bminusa'`, and `'both'`. So for your scenario, the following should work to set the subtract operation and the right token (B-A):

   `crear.parm('booleanop').set('subtract')`

   `crear.parm('subtractchoices').set('bminusa')`

I've found that searching through a node's 'Edit Parameter Interface' (small gear icon in top right of parameters) outlines the parameter names and options, such as tokens and other specific criteria.  For example, the Boolean's parameter 'Subtract Choices (substractchoices)' lists the available tokens under its Menu tab.